# Clock issue or set-reset issue: I am unsure how to debug and assess the situation

Tags: verilog, clock, pinout

I currently have two issues I'm not sure how to deal with, and I am unsure of which is preventing implementation.

I am trying to debug a memory interface and I am unsure of what to do. My first warning is flagging this line of code that is intended for testing the contents of the ram:

```vhdl
always@(posedge btnl or posedge btnr) begin : incriment_address
    if(btnl)
        read_address = read_address + 1;
    else if(btnr)
        read_address = read_address - 1;
end
```

```
[Synth 8-7137] Register read_address_reg in module ram_wrapper has both Set and reset with same priority. This may cause simulation mismatches. Consider rewriting code  ["C:/Users/lyndo/OneDrive/Documents/code/isa/risk_v/risc_v.srcs/sources_1/new/ram_wrapper.v":19]
```

I cannot see why this should be the case since the structure of the if-else if statement should assure that either one or the other must be true, but perhaps there is something I'm missing.

The error on the other hand says:

```
[Place 30-574] Poor placement for routing between an IO pin and BUFG. If this sub optimal condition is acceptable for this design, you may use the CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE constraint in the .xdc file to demote this message to a WARNING. However, the use of this override is highly discouraged. These examples can be used directly in the .xdc file to override this clock rule.
    < set_property CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE FALSE [get_nets btnr_IBUF] >

    btnr_IBUF_inst (IBUF.O) is locked to IOB_X0Y16
     and btnr_IBUF_BUFG_inst (BUFG.I) is provisionally placed by clockplacer on BUFGCTRL_X0Y0
```

I don't know if the error and warning are connected, but I figured it was best to include this to be safe. This is my declaration of the clock I wasn't sure to include:

```
set_property CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE FALSE [get_nets btnr_IBUF]
```

```
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W5 [get_ports clk]
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports clk]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synthesis tools require specific Verilog coding patterns, but your code does not adhere to any conventional pattern.  The tool is trying to match your code to a pattern like this:

```
always @(posedge clock or posedge reset) begin
    if (reset)
        read_address = <some constant value>;
    else 
        read_address = <any expression>;
end
```

This would infer sequential logic (a set of flip-flops), with the signal named `clock` as the clock input to the flops, and the signal named `reset` as the asynchronous reset input.  The Verilog names are not important.  Also, their order in the sensitivity list is not important.  What I showed in the pattern are common conventions.

It is fine to use one of the signals in the sensitivity list (`clock` or `reset`) in the body of the `always` block, but not both.  Your code uses both.  Therefore, the synthesis tool can not map your RTL code to any known logic implementation.

If you are trying to infer sequential logic, you need to adhere to the pattern.

See also: [Verilog example flip-flops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog#Example)

---

I added this code from the comment by the OP on this answer (the comment has been deleted as a routine clean-up). This is how the OP decided to re-write the code:

```
   always@(posedge clk, posedge rst) begin : incriment_address
      if(rst)
        read_address <= 0;
      else begin
         if(btnl)
           read_address <= read_address + 1;
         else if(btnr)
           read_address <= read_address - 1;
      end
   end
```